# Is $\ln(|x|)$ convex?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

I want to see if $\ln(|x|)$ is convex, given that $x \in (- \infty, + \infty)$. This is what I have tried (considering if the function is twice differentiable and greater than zero):

For $\ln(|x|)$ I consider two parts, $|x|=x$ for $x>0$, and $|x|=-x$ for $x<0$, then I apply the derivative in parts:

For $x>0$:
$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$ (first derivative)
$\frac{d^2}{d^2x} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$ (second derivative)

For $x<0$:
$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$ (first derivative)
$\frac{d^2}{d^2x} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$ (second derivative)

Then since the second derivative is the same for each case, I consider that the result means that is negative for any value of $x$, except in $x=0$. So the function $\ln(|x|)$ is not convex. Please, do you see a weakness in my approach? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. $\ln |x|$ is not convex over any interval on which it is defined.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSaving, to be honest I wasn't sure of this procedure, and sure I don't know how to type the formulas properly (still struggling with the notations). I appreciate your time on the answer.

Comment: "Is $\ln(abs(x))$ convex?" On what interval? The question isn't a very good one.

Comment: Hello @AdamRubinson, thanks for pointing the flaws in my question. Is there anything else to add/fix so this question is good for the community? I'll do my best to rewrite the question.

Comment: What is the value of your function when $x=0$? Asking for convexity on the whole real line is meaningless.

Comment: Hello @KaviRamaMurthy, what you mention was something that made me meditate. I cannot evaluate $ln(|x|)$ when x is 0, so should I change the interval to make it meaningful? Like, for every x >0? And for the first derivative, I cannot apply 1/x for x=0.

Comment: If the domain is $(0,\infty)$ then the function is concave, not convex.